# How to insert a new line in a [DisplayName] annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations

Is there anyway of putting a new line in a `[DisplayName()]` annotation of an mvc viewmodel?  I currently have a property that is:

```
[DisplayName("Delivery Time (if different from our normal delivery of 10-30am – 12.30pm):")]
public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }
```

and I want to have a new line after the Delivery Time part so that the bit in brackets is below, is that possible?  I've tried `\r\n` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem you have is that `\n` is ignored in html. You'd need to use `<br />` BUT that does tie your attribute metadata to using html formatting.

Comment: Hi, I tried that as well but all that happens is this, the <br /> is just displayed as part of the text on screen:

Delivery Time <br /> (if different from our normal delivery of 10-30am – 12.30pm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a prettier solutions, but a work around is presented in [How to add a new line into Display Attribute, Name field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879081/how-to-add-a-new-line-into-display-attribute-name-field)

To summarize you put a <br> (or <br/>) in your DisplayName string and use

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName)
```

to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `style="white-space: pre-line"` in your element and `\n` in `DisplayName` attribute. At least, it worked for me.