# How to add a new line into Display Attribute, Name field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I'm working on an MVC3 application and am using data attributes for the display name fields on the screen.  Below is a representative sample -

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Id (format \"9999\")")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [UIHint("StaffId")]
    public string StaffId { get; set; }
```

What I would like to do is to have the name display on two lines with line break right after "Id" text.  So it would display as

```
   Staff Id
   (format "9999")
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Staff Id<br/>(format \"9999\")")]
[StringLength(10)]
[UIHint("StaffId")]
public string StaffId { get; set; }
```

and inside your `StaffId.cshtml` custom editor template:

```
@model string
@Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName)
@Html.TextBox("")
```

Comment: A truly obvious solution once you think about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @Darin-Dimitrov answer, it is important to use

```
@Html.Raw(your.property)
```

Instead of typical HTML helpers like

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.property) -- will not work
```