# Line break in DisplayName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 with VB.Net and Razor.

In my model, I have:

`Public Class MPEmployee`

```
Public Property ID() As Integer
<DisplayName("Staff<br />Name")>
```

...
..
.

Is there any way of keeping the line break when I display the label for the column in my views:

```
<th>
  @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.StaffName) 
</th>
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: I really wouldn't put formatting in to these things, that is something the view or renderer should be doing.

Comment: possibly duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879081/how-to-add-a-new-line-into-display-attribute-name-field

Comment: Hi - I tried: @Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let view and html deal with breaking text into lines. If you give that `th` small enough width, it will automatically place `Name` on second line

```
Public Property ID() As Integer
<DisplayName("Staff Name")>
```

...

```
<th style="width:50px">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.StaffName) 
</th>
```